# Why can the mount points of debugfs and sysfs be overlapped?

Tags: filesystems, sysfs, debugfs

The mount point for debugfs is /sys/kernel/debug, and the mount point for sysfs is /sys/, why can these 2 mount points be overlapped without interference?

Comment: You seem to have no problem accepting that `/sys` is mounted inside of `/` or that `/dev` is mounted inside of `/` or that `/dev/shm` is mounted inside of `/dev` or that `/home` is mounted inside of `/` or that `/tmp` is mounted inside of `/` or that `/var/tmp` is mounted inside of `/`, so what is the difference that you perceive with `/sys` and `/sys/kernel/debug`?

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every directory can be a mountpoint, like / is a mountpoint, and /sys is too, or often /home is a separate mountpoint.

Comment: Suppose 1 filesystem is mounted on /foo and another is mounted on /foo/bar, then which filesystem do the contents under /foo/bar/ resides?

Comment: Of course the specific one, which is /foo/bar.